# Subtotal a Conditional Measure by Calendar Periods

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerpivot

For some context here are the tables involved (aside from the built-in Calendar Table)

##### LocationDim

| Location Code | Location Name | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LOC1 | Location 1 | CAT1 |
| LOC2 | Location 2 | CAT2 |

##### SalesFact

| Period | Location Code | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | LOC1 | 1000 |
| 2022-08-01 | LOC2 | 2000 |

I have a conditional measure which multiples the a simple countx measure if its value is above a threshold (eg. 5) that is dependent on the location's category.

```
[Volume] = COUNTX ( 'SalesFact', 'SalesFact'[Location Code] )
[MultiplierBase] =
VAR BranchCategory =
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( 'LocationDim'[Category] ),
        VALUES ( 'LocationDim'[Category] )
    )
VAR TargetVolume =
    IF ( OR ( BranchCategory = "CAT2", BranchCategory = "CAT3" ), 2, 5 )
VAR CurrentVolume = [Volume]
VAR Result = 
    IF (
        AND ( HASONEVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Date] ), HASONEVALUE ( 'LocationDim'[Location Code] ) ),
        IF ( CurrentVolume >= TargetVolume, [Volume] * 5 )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Now the dilema is that, as experienced dax users may know, the built-in subtotal wouldn't be able to facilitate the conditional logic of the measure. What I'm currently attempting is to use the measure above as a "base/reference" measure and compute the subtotals in a separate measure. However, with multiple attempts I am unable to get the appropriate subtotals. Below is what I latest iteration of my multiple attempts, however it is still wrong.

```
    CALCULATE (
        SUMX ( 'SalesFact', [MultiplierBase] ),
        'Calendar'[Date] <= MaxDate,
        'Calendar'[Date] >= MinDate,
        ALL ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
    )
```

##### Expected Result

###### Daily Timeframe (- is placeholder for blanks)

| Row Labels | 2022-08-02 | 2022-08-02 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **LOC2** | - | - |
| Volume | 2 | 1 |
| MultiplierBase | 10 | - |

###### Monthly Timeframe (- is placeholder for blanks)

| Row Labels | August 2022 |
| --- | --- |
| **LOC2** | - |
| Volume | 3 |
| MultiplierBase | 10 |

Comment: Perhaps you should increase the number of rows in each of your tables to ten or so and include some expected results. Also, you haven't shared the definition for the measure [Volume] which you are currently referencing.

Comment: Edited with expected results.